# magento 1.9 google analytics ecommerce tracking not working

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics, google-api

Orders not tracked in Google analytics, otherwise the number of visitors is tracked. Note that:

1. E-commerce enabled in ga account
2. Google API enabled + tracking code in place
3. I tried to implement js tracking code manually in success page as following https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#example
4. I'm testing with checkmo method in order to get native Magento behaviour but nothing works

Am I missing something? any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: have you clear Magento Cache After adding Tracking Code in backend.?

Comment: First thing to check is your checkout success page. If the code is there and has order values, verify it for correctness against Google documentation.

Comment: cache was cleared , the thing that I don't see the js code generated by the block ga.php ( _AddTrans , etc ...) in success page , it seems not generated or returned empty , except the common ga tracking code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it , it was a conflict with payment method module (klarna 5.2) which override block/ga.php. just some xml configuration solve the problem or upgrade to klarna 5.3. Now it's working!

Comment: Here we have the same problem with Klarna 5.3.1. Can you share the xml configuration changes that solves the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the delay
 '<default>
-        <reference name="google_analytics">
+        <reference name="head">
+            <action method="unsetChild">
<name>google_analytics</name>   </action>
<block type="klarna/klarnacheckout_ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
         </reference>
     </default>'

-   line to  be removed

Comment: Thanks Sabri. So you mean I should find above mentioned tags in klarna xml file and remove it. But there is no such tags?

Comment: Actually as I mentioned earlier, all my projects are using 5.2 version so maybe they changed the xml structure in 5.3 ! it could be ... anyway, do we talk about the same file ?  app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/vaimo_klarna.xml

Comment: Thanks Sabri, I was looking in another xml. Can I just remove <default>
        <reference name="google_analytics">
            <block type="klarna/klarnacheckout_ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default> ?